# Passing a POJO to a custom control property

Tags: xpages, pojo

I'm refactoring an XPages application which has five nested repeat controls repeating basically the same thing (an xp:panel). I thought, aha, here comes a custom control with properties!

I'm looping my repeat controls around properties of a managed bean, and I was hoping I could have set a property for the custom control to just accept the POJO I'm sending it (and then access it with EL within the custom control).

What should I do? Make the custom control receive only strings, numbers, etc and have the whole nested-control logic outside? Or is there a trick?

Comment: Hmm what about a HashMap instead of a whole POJO? But: with both POJO and Map you are able to access properties via the methods (e.g. getValue() or getMyAwesomePropertyValue()). The CC property though should be of type java.lang.Object

Comment: Make him accept an object. So you can pass what ever Java object to the custom control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom control can easily accept a java object that's passed in via the custom properties.  Just use the type:  java.lang.Object

Answer (score 1):

All the answers were correct, but only David put it as an answer - thanks to all!

I've noted my code here for anyone later: I defined node to be of Type java.lang.Object. Notice the syntax to get the object into the custom control:

```
<xp:repeat
    id="repeatfirstlevelnode"
    value="#{TableOfContents.root.children}"
    var="firstlevelnode">
    <xc:ccPanelNavigation
        node="#{firstlevelnode}"
        panelStyleWhenActive="panelLevel1 active bold"
        panelStyleWhenInactive="panelLevel1"
        NameNestedRepeatControl="repeatsecondlevelnodes">
    </xc:ccPanelNavigation>
```

And once you're in the custom control, you access the property with CompositeData.YourObject.

```
<xp:image
            id="imgDummy"
            url="/dummyEC.png"
            styleClass="imageDummy">
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{not compositeData.node.hasChildren}]]></xp:this.rendered>
        </xp:image>
```